# What term to use to refer to a late husband's last name after marrying again and taking the new husband's name?

Tags: single-word-requests, surnames, convention

When I married my first husband I took his name and used the term "nee" to quickly refer to my birth name.  After my first husband died, I remarried and took my new husband's last name.  Now I want to know what term to use to refer to my first husband's last name, similar to how I would have used the term "nee" before. I suppose I could say "previous surname" but was hoping there was a shorter way to express this.

As an example, in letter I used to sign my name "Elaine Hornung" and follow it with "nee Elaine Rae" for instances where it might be important for the receiver of the letter to know my birth name.  Now I want to sign my name and follow it with the birth name and my previous married name, Wintonyk. The term for that use is what I am looking for.

Comment: FWIW, "nee" is a loan word from French, and means "born" or "birth" having the same "na" roots as "prenatal, neonatal."  Thus, it only applies to your original name, not any intermediates.

Comment: There is no such term. Why would there be? By the way, it's Jane Smith née Oldstone. You don't repeat the first name....

Comment: I see the need for it. If I’d been receiving letters from E Wintonyk, then suddenly get a letter from E Hornung (and I know more than one Elaine), it would be nice to clarify who this is without having to ask. You could just add a "formerly Wintonyk". Unfortunately I don’t know if there’s a way to differentiate widowed and divorced.

Comment: @Pam Some old British etiquette  guides would suggest "Mrs John Smith" for married/widowed women and "Mrs Mary Smith" for divorced women, which could presumably be applied with 'formerly' here.

Comment: Janet Smith, formerly Jones, née Jackson - is how I understand it is done. Thus Janet was born Jackson, then changed her name to Jones and is now called Smith.

Comment: Dan's answer was down-scroll and I didn't notice it. Agreed.

Comment: French née, feminine of né, literally, born, past participle of naître to be born, from Latin nasci

Comment: @origimbo Yes! I noticed this looking at [this](https://www.hitched.co.uk/wedding-planning/invite-wording-and-etiquette/wedding-invitation-wording_527.htm) guide to wedding invitation etiquette. You can tell so much about the family situation if it's phrased correctly without ever needing to ask.

Comment: All the suggestions so far sound great ('formerly' sounds right to me) but you'd think there'd be an etiquette book that would cover this not uncommon situation.

Comment: Take it one step further.  (1) Born; (2)  Married; (3) Divorced; (4) Married someone else; (5) Divorced from (4);  (6) Resumes birth name.   Then what?  And if there are several remarriages and several divorces?  I think one just sends an e-mail notice to everyone one has ever known.  Make it funny, because it is.  Or, for the specific case the OP asks about  "Elaine Wintonyk, nee Rae, déflorée Hornung"  I know this is tasteless.  Sorry, couldn't help myself

Comment: Wide range of choices eg *formerly, previously, aka, was, till I ditched the bastard*. Depends on connotations. Don't know why you'd want to proclaim your divorced status rather than use something more generic, but I hear people have divorce parties these days.

Answer (score 5):

You might say

> Elaine Hornung (formerly Wintonyk; née Rae).

Or, in the case of my mother,

> Mrs Monica Mann (also known as Dr Zealley); formerly Lloyd, née Zealley

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the person asking, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.

Comment: Anecdotally agreed. Not sure how to document this.

Comment: thank you for all the answers.  It seems for me that I will have to go with "formerly".  Too bad there isn't a shorter word though.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully an etiquette expert will write a definitive answer here.  But in the meantime, I'll give you a couple of ideas.  Let's say you used to be Jane Smith, and now you married Mr. López.

> Jane (Smith) López
>
> Jane Smith López
>
> Jane López (formerly Jane Smith)
>
> Jane López (widow of Smith) - *this one is inspired by the way one does this in Spanish*
>
> Jane Smith, now Jane López

Also, some people hyphenate.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the first approach in `Dan`'s answer used and thought it simple, and to the point.

In my family that has been done by a couple women keeping the names active for children from each marriage. Never really considered the second need he shows, that of keeping a woman's professional persona intact, but that seems like it could be a bigger thing over coming years.

Commenting on `Dan`'s answer, the poster looks for a shorter word. One feels the use of *née* sets up a small demand for a French word so perhaps *déjà*. As in `Abby (déjà Collins, déjà Durham, déjà Eddings, née Brown) Franklin`.

(Admittedly though, all I know about French is how to click it for the output language in Google Translate, so perhaps *déjà* is hopelessly inappropriate.)

Of course, nowadays, women facing the question of a connected persona in, say, FaceBook, seem to simply use their birth names with at most a following current last name. So maybe that will be considered "the" way for the future.

Comment: Does your suggestion have any established use in English?

Comment: Please do not use code markdown here. We set mentions in italic, or quote them instead.